# Cannot sign in with Apple in iOS simulator

Tags: ios, xcode, ios-simulator, icloud, apple-sign-in

I cannot log in with my Apple credentials from an iOS app I am developing in the iOS simulator. When I enter the password, the indicator is waiting forever.

- The app, when run on a real device logs in properly
- I have tried with more than one account with the same result.

I am working with XCode 12 in macOS Cataline 10.15

[image: cannot login with Apple account]

Comment: did you find a solution?

Comment: Does anybody find the solution ?

Comment: Same issue. Any solutions?

Comment: Appreciate if someone can give us a solution on this.